# Android soft keyboard - Working with onbackpressed method

Tags: android, kotlin

When I press the back button on my Android phone it closes the soft keyboard, but when calling onbackpressed method it doesn't close the soft keyboard

I have tried to close the soft keyboard programmatically, but I could not solve the problem exactly

```
val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

    if (imm.isAcceptingText){
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
        android.R.id.accessibilityActionHideTooltip

    }*
```

I want to close the soft keyboard while calling the onbackpressed method, How exactly does the back button work in Android?

If I call the onbackpressed method I need to close the soft keyboard programmatically, I need to avoid that closing keyboard code

Comment: And for your other question calling `onBackPress()` will not close the keyboard because keyboard closing event on back button pressed is handled by system itself and consumed also. If you manually trigger `onBackPress()` it will not call that hiding piece of code..

Answer (score 1):

This should close your keyboard

```
    window!!.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)
```

or create a function

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    val imm = activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    //currently focused view
    var view = activity.currentFocus
    //If null, create a new one
    if (view == null) {
        view = View(activity)
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

and call

```
    hideKeyboard(your_activity_context as YourActivity)
```